# How can i Decrypt this encrypting method in PHP

Tags: php

So ive got this encrypting code which encrypts a pass word with 3 salts this is

```
$salt1 = "hey";
$salt1= md5($salt1);
$salt2= "yeh";
$salt1= md5($salt2);
$salt3= "hye";
$salt1= md5($salt3);
$password1= $salt1.$password1.$salt3;
$password1= md5($password1.$salt2);
```

:how would i decrypt this?

thanks for your help!

Comment: There are methods to decrypt it, i.e. brute force. MD5 should not be used at all now. It is unsecured. Use `sha512` for example.

Comment: Bring a nice bouquet of flowers and a box of Belgian chocolate to the secretary of the company which uses this code. Works all the time ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't decrypt it. [MD5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) is only one way. Two different strings can have the same output with MD5, so it's impossible to decipher the original string.

About the only way to crack MD5 is if the password is a dictionary word or easy to guess and used without a seed. With a seed, it's practically impossible, especially if there's no way to guess what the seed is.

Comment: Although MD5 is so outdated, you should be able to brute force reverse it quite fast.

Comment: @GolezTrol - Like I said in the post, multiple strings can have the same output, so you are brute forcing it to what jumble of seemingly random characters?

Comment: @PédeLeão http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8607/how-quickly-can-these-password-schemes-really-be-beaten (might be interesting for others too who dare to use md5 as a password scheme)

Comment: @Sumurai8 in the answer you linked the author is talking about hashes where the salt is *known to the attacker*. Totally different story.

Comment: @LukasGraf In case of an attack, it is likely that the attacker will have that information. There are two reasons to use a salt: An attacker will have to make new rainbow tables with your salt with a shared salt. With MD5, this can be done in an alarming small time. The second, more important reason to use salts, is to use an unique salt for every entry. While the salt might be known to the attacker, they have to guess each password seperatelly, exponentially increasing the time that one needs to get all passwords.